# Routing with objects

Tags: php, routes, twig

I am trying to pass values from my query builder results and to match the dateFrom and dateTo as parts of individual route for every passed result in an table for downloading XLSX file.

Error is that every varibale I write does not exist.

My service

```
public function getTransaction($dateFrom, $dateTo)
{

    $queryBuilder = $this->getMyRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select('p')
        ->where('p.date >= :from')
        ->andWhere('p.date <= :to')
        ->setParameter('from', $dateFrom->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->setParameter('to',   $dateTo->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->orderBy('p.id');
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

/**
 * @Route("/export-invoice/{dateFrom}/{dateTo}/{id}", name="export_invoice")
 */
public function downloadInvoice($dateFrom, $dateTo)
{

    $dateOf = $this->get('app')->getTransaction(
        $dateFrom, $dateTo
    );


}
```

and in my twig

```
 <a href="{{ path("export_invoice", { dateFrom: dateOf.dateFrom, dateTo: "dateTo", id: "id" }) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-download"></i> XLSX</a>
```

Comment: Your functions aren't returning anything?

Comment: Variable "" does not exist, every time. @DarkBee

Comment: I'm meaning your functions `downloadInvoice` and `getTransaction` don't have a return statement, thus returning `null` which is prolly causing the error.